# Asciidoc: a2x does not generate numbered sections anymore

Tags: asciidoc, a2x

a2x does not generate numbered sections anymore, though I have the following attributes defined:

```
= Some title
:toc:
:numbered:
```

It used to work once (I think it was before I've updated Kubuntu to the latest LTS version (16.04.2 LTS)).

Comment: can you paste the output with the `--verbose` flag on?